# TYPO3 EventDispatcherInterface

Tags: events, typo3, typo3-10.x, php-7.4, event-dispatching

I try to inject the `$eventDispatcher` in my Repository

`private EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher;`

```
public function injectEventDispatcher(EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher): void
    {
        $this->eventDispatcher = $eventDispatcher;
    }
```

But since PHP 7.4 you have to be initialized. But I cant initialize the EventDispatcherInterface and get this error :
Typed property $eventDispatcher must not be accessed before initialization

How can I initialize the eventDispatcher? Thanks.

Comment: Did you initialize your class variable `$this->eventDispatcher` before your inject method?

Comment: Please add more code, just from this snippet it is unclear how you get your error. Also you should consider doing event dispatching outside of the repository, e.g. by wrapping it with a different class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, switching to [Constructor Injection](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/DependencyInjection/Index.html#constructor-injection) can solve this:

```
public function __construct(EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher)
{
    $this->eventDispatcher = $eventDispatcher;
}
```